# What is the purpose of `Array#include?` as compared to `Array#index`?

Tags: ruby, arrays

`Array#include?` provides only a weaker information than what `Array#index` provides, i.e., when `Array#index` returns `nil`, the corresponding method call with `Array#include?` will return `false`, and when `Array#index` returns an integer, `Array#include?` returns `true`. Furthermore, comparing the two indicates that there is no significant difference in speed; rather `Array#index` often shows a better result than `Array#include?`:

```
a = %w[boo zoo foo bar]

t = Time.now
10000.times do
  a.include?("foo")
end
puts Time.now - t # => 0.005626235

t = Time.now
10000.times do
  a.index("foo")
end
puts Time.now - t # => 0.003683945
```

Then, what is the purpose of `Array#include?`? Can't all code using it be rewritten using `Array#index`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779451/why-is-array-index-faster-than-array-include

Comment: Your linked question answers the performance issues, but one reason that `Array#include?` is present is because it is inherited from Enumerable.

Comment: @Sparhawk Right. But `Array` could have overwritten `include?` with its current `index` functionality. That would have made it simpler (except for the trickiness of `?` used for non-boolean).

Comment: I guess if there's not a strong argument to change the behaviour, then it'd be best to keep the inherited behaviour for consistency with other enumerables. Not necessarily very convincing, I know, but perhaps the argument for consistency with `?`s suggests a similar thought process.

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't an official reason, but I can think of a few things:

- Clarity: as a name, include? makes more sense at first sight, and also allows easy visual confirmation of code correctness by identifying itself as a boolean predicate. This follows the concept of making wrong code look wrong (see http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html)
- Good typing: If all you want is a boolean value for a boolean check, making that a number could lead to bugs
- Cleanliness: Isn't it nicer to see a printed output of "true" rather than going back to C and having no boolean to speak of?

Comment: @sawa: In C, there is no boolean type. 0 is false, everything else is true. People started doing all sorts of clever tricks using integers as booleans, and vice versa, and multiplying them, and all that, and it just turns into a mess.

Comment: Technically C *does* have a boolean type. Unless by "C" you mean "whatever old version of C that MS supports".

Comment: @muistooshort: What is it? I've never seen it.

Comment: It is part of C99 but you have to `#include <stdbool.h>` to use it.