# Why is array.index faster than array.include?

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance

I'm working with some large datasets, and trying to improve performance. I need to determine whether an object is contained in an array. I was considering using either `index` or `include?`, so I benchmarked both.

```
require 'benchmark'

a = (1..1_000_000).to_a
num = 100_000
reps = 100

Benchmark.bmbm do |bm|
  bm.report('include?') do
    reps.times { a.include? num }
  end
  bm.report('index') do
    reps.times { a.index num }
  end
end
```

Surprisingly (to me), `index` was considerably faster.

```
               user     system      total        real
include?   0.330000   0.000000   0.330000 (  0.334328)
index      0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.039812)
```

Since `index` provides more information than `include?`, I would have expected it to be slightly slower if anything, although this was not the case. Why is it faster?

(I know that `index` comes directly from the array class, and `include?` is inherited from Enumerable. Might that explain it?)

Comment: Nice catch. I think you should file an issue to MRI.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729175/what-is-the-purpose-of-arrayinclude-as-compared-to-arrayindex

Comment: @undur_gongor Thanks. And [done](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10227).

Comment: @Sparhawk: The [issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10227) has been fixed since.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the Ruby MRI source, it seems that `index` uses the optimized `rb_equal_opt` while `include?` uses `rb_equal`. This can be seen in [rb_ary_includes](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/c6da45b74cf9d420803c6ccbf4d527b1dfe4014e/array.c#L3851) and  [rb_ary_index](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/c6da45b74cf9d420803c6ccbf4d527b1dfe4014e/array.c#L1462). [Here](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi?revision=42704&view=revision) is the commit that made the change. Its not immediately clear to me why its used in `index` and not `include?`

You might also find it interesting to read the discussion of this [feature](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8820)

Answer (score 1):

I ran the same test for benchmarking. Seems like include? is faster than index, though it is not very consistent.
Here are my results for two different scenarios.

1. ruby code is same as yours

```
               user     system      total        real
index      0.065803   0.000652   0.066455 (  0.067181)
include?   0.065551   0.000590   0.066141 (  0.066894)
```

2. Another benchmark

```
                   user     system      total        real
    index      0.000034   0.000005   0.000039 (  0.000037)
    include?   0.000017   0.000001   0.000018 (  0.000017)
```

code:

```
require 'benchmark'

# parse ranks and return number of reports to using index
def solution_using_index(ranks)
  return 0 if ranks.nil? || ranks.empty? || ranks.length <= 1
  return ((ranks[0] - ranks[1] == 1) || (ranks[1] - ranks[0] == 1) ?  1 : 0) if ranks.length == 2
  return 0 if ranks.max > 1000000000 || ranks.min < 0

  grouped_ranks = ranks.group_by(&:itself)
  report_to, rank_keys= 0, grouped_ranks.keys
  rank_keys.each {|rank| report_to += grouped_ranks[rank].length if rank_keys.index(rank+1) }
  report_to
end

# parse ranks and return number of reports to using include
def solution_using_include(ranks)
  return 0 if ranks.nil? || ranks.empty? || ranks.length <= 1
  return ((ranks[0] - ranks[1] == 1) || (ranks[1] - ranks[0] == 1) ?  1 : 0) if ranks.length == 2
  return 0 if ranks.max > 1000000000 || ranks.min < 0

  grouped_ranks = ranks.group_by(&:itself)
  report_to, rank_keys= 0, grouped_ranks.keys
  rank_keys.each {|rank| report_to += grouped_ranks[rank].length if rank_keys.include?(rank+1) }
  report_to
end

test_data = [[3, 4, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0], [4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 0], [4, 2, 0] ]

Benchmark.bmbm do |bm|
  bm.report('index') do
    test_data.each do |ranks|
      reports_to = solution_using_index(ranks)
    end
  end
  bm.report('include?') do
    test_data.each do |ranks|
      reports_to = solution_using_include(ranks)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your results seem internally consistent to me? `include?` is always faster. However, did you read the comments? The bug has been fixed, hence your results.

Comment: yes, it was misleading for me, so wanted to justify it. I tested it with 2.6.0, 2.6.0preview1, 2.6.0preview2, 2.6.0preview3 and its consistent.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is your goal, you should be using Array#bsearch which traverses the array using binary search.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch

```
a.bsearch {|a| num <=> a }
```

It smokes both`index` and `include`

```
Rehearsal --------------------------------------------
include?   0.108172   0.000805   0.108977 (  0.112928)
index      0.122730   0.000502   0.123232 (  0.126323)
bsearch    0.000254   0.000027   0.000281 (  0.000354)
----------------------------------- total: 0.232490sec

               user     system      total        real
include?   0.106727   0.000036   0.106763 (  0.108495)
index      0.107732   0.000330   0.108062 (  0.110272)
bsearch    0.000201   0.000008   0.000209 (  0.000206)
```